# iOS, Audio Queue: Buffer size is not contant

Tags: iphone, ios, audioqueueservices, audioqueue

I use **Audio Queue Services** in my application. When allocating the buffer, I set the buffer size to 30000 samples:

```
AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(mQueue, 30000, &mBuffers[i]);
```

But the subsequent calls of the callback are made with the following *inNumberPacketDescriptions*:

```
30000
30000
30000
26928
30000
30000
```

They aren't always equal to 30000. **Why?**

Record format configuration (using *CAStreamBasicDescription*):

```
mRecordFormat.mSampleRate = kSampleRate;    
mRecordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
mRecordFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
mRecordFormat.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;
mRecordFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
mRecordFormat.mBytesPerPacket = mRecordFormat.mBytesPerFrame = (mRecordFormat.mBitsPerChannel / 8) * mRecordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
mRecordFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
```

**3** buffers are used.

Comment: Is that in a single recording session? Usually the last chunk will be less than 30000, because there were not that many samples. Are you pausing and resuming the recording at the points where packet count is less than 30000? Also how have you configured the data format in `AudioStreamBasicDescription`?

Comment: There's no pauses or stops. Attached record format configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I've seen iOS freak out and spontaneously change buffer sizes when presented with a non-power-of-two audio buffer. ([Another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633412/ios-bug-in-the-simulator-using-audiounitrender) references this) Anyway,

30000 is

(a) a HUGE buffer size, and

(b) a weird number to use for a buffer. Usually they're in powers of 2— i.e. `*=2` from 64, i.e. 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096. I've never seen one higher than 4096, and I do a lot of audio work.

If you have a specialized reason to use unusually-large buffers, you could use a `nextPowerOfTwo` convenience function or just hard-code the math yourself.

Comment: Probably, but it's not an answer to the questions why. If the buffer size is power of two, will it be always constant?

Comment: @buildsucceeded - thanks. upvote for you. was trying to resolve why some code i wrote worked fine on IOs7 on the ipad mini, and in the simulator, but on an iphone 4s just ignored all audio data. dropped the buffer size down and hey presto. worky worky.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense if you think about it, there's a finite amount of memory in the device for those buffers, which must be statically-allocated for performance reasons.

Comment: Hi, just a follow-up question. What is affected by the buffer size? What is the difference when I set it to 1024 rather than 4096 or how is it calculated? Will this affect the quality of the recorded audio? I set the sample rate to 16k so, how would I know the size of the buffer that should be set? Thanks!

Comment: @finalstatic quality isn't affected *unless* the buffer size is too small for the audio to be processed before the next batch of audio comes in, in which case you'll get glitches. A larger buffer size means more latency, but if you're not doing live monitoring (and not hugely memory constrained) a reasonably large buffer size (512 or 1024) will serve you well.

Comment: @finalstatic There are also "normal" sample rates: 48k, 44.1k, and half or a quarter of those. You *can* use any sample rate you want, but to avoid weird interoperational problems I'd start with one of those unless you have a reason not to.

Comment: Understood. Thanks!