# iOS: Bug in the simulator using AudioUnitRender

Tags: ios, core-audio, simulator

I have hit yet another iOS simulator bug.   My question is, is there some workaround?

Bug is this:

Load apple's **AurioTouch** sample Project.

and simply print out the number of frames getting received by the **render callback** (in aurioTouchAppDelegate.mm)

```
static OSStatus PerformThru(
                            void                        *inRefCon, 
                            AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  *ioActionFlags, 
                            const AudioTimeStamp        *inTimeStamp, 
                            UInt32                      inBusNumber, 
                            UInt32                      inNumberFrames, 
                            AudioBufferList             *ioData)
{
    printf( "%u, ", (unsigned int)inNumberFrames );
```

I get the following output:

```
471, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, ...
```

However, if you comment out the call to **AudioUnitRender** on the next line:

```
{
    printf( "%u, ", (unsigned int)inNumberFrames );

    aurioTouchAppDelegate *THIS = (aurioTouchAppDelegate *)inRefCon;
    OSStatus err = 0; // AudioUnitRender(THIS->rioUnit, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, 1, inNumberFrames, ioData);
```

It now sends an appropriate number of floats each time.

```
471, 470, 471, 470, 470, 471, 470, 471, 470, 470, 471, 470, 471, 470, 470, 471, 470,
```

Another question I have is: why such a random number as 470, 471?   I read somewhere that you specify the buffer length implicitly by specifying its time duration, and it sets the buffer length to *the power of two that yields the best approximation to this duration*.   But empirical evidence suggests this is not so.

Anyway, pretty sure this is a bug.  I'm going to go on file it.  If anyone can shed some light, please do!

Comment: I can't provide you with a specific answer but if there's one thing I've learned with iOS audio it's that the simulator uses a completely different stack that causes all kinds of weirdness. I'd do all testing on the device if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the workaround to Simulator bugs is to test the app on the device. The iOS Simulators is just a simulator, not an emulator.

The iOS Simulator has some odd bugs. It may have to do with buffer sizes according to this post by Christopher Penrose:

> The simulator will act wildly different setup to setup as it relies on your host audio gear, which may in your case be a third-party interface.  I have seen the simulator refuse a reasonable power of 2 size because of the device.  I have not been able to use audio in the simulator reliably.
>   James is telling me that I am being foolish but in practice I have been able to rely on the original configured buffer size without having it change on me.

Link with possibly more helpful info: http://osdir.com/ml/coreaudio-api/2010-04/msg00150.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the audio working with your simulator, you need to make sure your samplerate is set to 44.1k in OS X's audio/midi setup tool.  AVAudioSession/Audio Services will report your samplerate as 44.1k no matter what it actually is when using the simulator.

By setting your mac's samplerate to 44.1k, you'll get a consistent inNumberFrames (default is 1024) per callback, although this can still allegedly be changed by the system (ex. app goes to background).